# Updating a value with the same thing is considered as updating in triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table with multiple users named 'Bob' for example and I run the following the query:

```
UPDATE CLIENTS_LIST 
SET client_name = 'Bob' 
WHERE client_name = 'Bob'
```

Is the trigger going to get fired in that case? Is it considered as updating or not?

What I'm trying to know here is If its going to be necessary to compare the old value with the new or not.

Comment: Yes this is an update and yes it will be fired.

Comment: So there is a need to compare values (the old with the new)?

Comment: @Dablackninja Yes. More info on other effects of non-updating updates here: [The Impact of Non-Updating Updates - Paul White](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx)

Comment: The [`Update()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql) _function_ will also indicate that the column was updated. The `deleted` and `inserted` tables must be used to obtain the _before_ and _after_ values for the rows that the `UPDATE` statement affected.